# Can't access WPF user control in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am using the following markup to define my controls. I have seen various other examples of the point of declaring the `x:Name` attribute which I have done, but I still cannot select my control in the code behind.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AMTR2.UI.Controls.CustomColumnsBuilderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
                        d:DesignHeight="332" d:DesignWidth="1038">


    <Canvas>
        <ListView Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="48" Height="183" Name="listView1" 
            Width="453" 
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Order" Width="100" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Display Name" Width="290" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Width" Width="50" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}"></GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="moveUpButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="50" Content="Move Up" 
            Height="22" Width="74" IsEnabled="False"  />

        <Button Name="moveDownButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="80" Content="Move Down" 
            Height="22" Width="74" IsEnabled="False"  />


        <Button Name="deleteButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="removeButton_Click" Canvas.Top="110" Content="Delete" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

        <Button Name="addButton" Click="addColumn" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="140" Content="Add Item" 
            Height="22" Width="74" />

        <Label Content="Name:" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="250" />

        <TextBox x:Name="txtDsiplayName"  Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"   
            Width="450.4"  />

        <Label Content="Width:"   Canvas.Left="470" Canvas.Top="250" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtWdith" Canvas.Left="470"  Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"  
            Width="70.4" 
             />

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I am trying to access the control using the following routine in my code behind. I am coming from a winforms background so excuse me if this is not the correct way to go about it.

```
private void addColumn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

        _ColumnsModeList.Add(new CustomColumnsModel
        {
            DisplayNameOverride =txtDsiplayName.Text,
            Width =100,
            Order=1
        });
    }
```

Comment: @IVAAAN123 can you please provided and example thanks

Comment: I was wrong, you can access it through code behind)

Comment: @rogue39nin, did you ever figure out why it wasn't working?

Comment: @NightmareGames this was long ago i cant even remember this quesiton now lol

Answer (score 0):

you can access any control by his name, for exemple:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AMTR2.UI.Controls.CustomColumnsBuilderControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
                    d:DesignHeight="332" d:DesignWidth="1038">


<Canvas>
    <ListView Name="listView" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="48" Height="183" Name="listView1" 
        Width="453" 
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order" Width="100" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Display Name" Width="290" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Width" Width="50" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}"></GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name="moveUpButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="50" Content="Move Up" 
        Height="22" Width="74" IsEnabled="False"  />

    <Button Name="moveDownButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="80" Content="Move Down" 
        Height="22" Width="74" IsEnabled="False"  />


    <Button Name="deleteButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="removeButton_Click" Canvas.Top="110" Content="Delete" 
        Height="22" Width="74"  />

    <Button Name="addButton" Click="addColumn" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="140" Content="Add Item" 
        Height="22" Width="74" />

    <Label Content="Name:" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="250" />

    <TextBox x:Name="txtDsiplayName"  Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"   
        Width="450.4"  />

    <Label Content="Width:"   Canvas.Left="470" Canvas.Top="250" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtWdith" Canvas.Left="470"  Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"  
        Width="70.4" 
         />

</Canvas>
```

in your code behind you indicate the name of the control, in this case **listView**.

Comment: you want to access the control from outside !

Comment: refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757540/access-wpf-user-control-value

Comment: I don't see the difference between this example and the example in the question.